# SonarQube Eclipse Plugin: Incremental scan scans all files, not just those modified locally

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I am using version 3.4 of the SonarQube Eclipse Plugin and when I analyze a project, the scan is successful, but it scans all files. I know that the default scan mode is 'incremental' for this plugin, so I do not know why the analysis is scanning all of my files and not just those that I have modified locally. I have SonarQube running successfully on a server and I can view all of the current issues in my project using a web browser.

Also, when I view the sonar-report.json file that is generated on my computer as a result of the scan, all of the issues have the 'isNew' tag set to true and the update date equals the creation date which equals the time of the scan. I know this is incorrect because some of the issues are pre-existing and should have a creation date of a month ago because this is what I see when looking at the issue on my server through my web browser.

To me it seems as if Eclipse is not synchronizing the existing issues properly with the server because it seems to not recognize any of them. Please let me know what may be wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a branch (sonar.branch) in your regular SQ analysis? Can you share logs of the analysis?

Comment: I never set the sonar.branch property in Eclipse or in the server, so I think I am not using it. How can I send you the logs? Email?

Comment: You can upload logs on a service like http://pastebin.com/. If you think they may contains sensitive data then yes send them to me privately (julien.henry _at_ sonarsource.com)

Comment: Is you project correctly associated in Eclipse. Please check the project key in SQ server, then compare with the project key in Eclipse (Right click on project -> properties -> SonarQube -> Key)

Comment: Yes it is. The Key is correct and the Server URL is correct (I know this because I copied the URL to my web browser and was able to see all of the issues for my project on the browser).

Comment: Can you try to run an incremental preview analysis outside of Eclipse to see if you get the same results? For exemple if you have a Maven project: `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.host.url=http://xxxx`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It is not a Maven project, so how else could I initiate a scan outside of Eclipse?

Comment: Use SonarQube Runner command line utility.

Comment: I ran the sonar-runner.bat file and got similar results using the same sonar analysis parameters. The project did not seem to recognize that any of the issues are already existing on the server.

Comment: Could I be missing a configuration in either the server or the scan?

Comment: Usually when people have such issue this is because there project is not correctly associated, ie the project key they pass via `-Dsonar.projectKey` is not the same as the the project key on server side. As a result the analysis is like if it was the first analysis of a project: all files are analyzed and all issues are "new".

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately, the keys are the same. Is this a problem you have heard of before?

Comment: If association is correct then second possibility is a file checksum issue. What is your version of SQ server?

Comment: When I run the scan, it says 5.0.1